# Why if(value=="imperial") does not work in Android?

Tags: android, string

I am unable to understand why this code doesn't work

```
if(value=="imperial"){
   high=high*1.8 + 32;
   low=low*1.8 + 32;
        }
```

But when I use the equals() method then it works fluently....

```
if(value.equals(getString(R.string.imperial))){
                high=high*1.8 + 32;
                low=low*1.8 + 32;}
```

where value is a string and R.string.imperial refers to the string "imperial".

Comment: `==` compares actual objects I think. Try `.equals("imperial")`

Comment: `==` vs `.equals()` : A `String` is an object, so you're comparing the location in memory of `value` against the location in memory of the `String` literal `"imperial"`. Their memory locations are different, thus `==` fails while `.equals()` is overriden by the `String` class to compare the `char` values. So if `value = "imperial"` then `value.equals("imperial")` is `true`.
Note: some people use `"imperial".equals(value)` instead, this removes the possibility of a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you should use `.equals` when you want to test if two strings are equal. `==` tests reference equality, while `.equals` test value equality.

For a more in depth answer, take a look at the question [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

See this related stackoverflow question: [Java String.equals vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

From an answer to that question by @Alnitak:

> Use the string.equals(String other) function to compare strings, not
>   the == operator.
>
> The function checks the actual contents of the string, the == operator
>   checks whether the references to the objects are equal. Note that
>   string constants are usually "interned" such that two constants with
>   the same value can actually be compared with ==, but it's better not
>   to rely on that.